# How can I remove paint left from an appliance dolly from the front of a washer?

Tags: paint-removal

My husband was moving our washing machine with a dolly.  He dropped the washing machine and now the front has dents and green paint from the dolly. How do I get the green paint off from the front of the washer?

Comment: Make him remove it. "You break it, you buy it" policy!

Answer (score 1):

You might try a Mr. Clean Magic Eraser

Answer (score 0):

The paint from the Dollie is probably enamel, **the same stuff** on the washing machine.

**TEST** all methods in an inconspicuous area first! and let any wet methods dry, to check for hazing.

As a last resort, use [acetone](https://www.google.com/search?q=does%20acatone%20remove%20emanamel%3E&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=does%20acetone%20remove%20enamel).

But give the soft side of a sponge, water and elbow grease a shot first. A plastic scraper might help, but be delicate. I round the corners on any trowel I use to 'finish scrape' so that it doesn't scratch the surface. Bic lighters have a nice soft, rounded edge along the bottom, excellent for scraping without scratching on small jobs.

Acetone <strike>risks destroying</strike> *will* destroy the finish on the washer. Be quick with it and don't let it sit.

Comment: [Appliance spray paint](https://www.google.com/search?q=Appilance+spray+paint&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=Appliance+spray+paint&spell=1) is good stuff if it's totally shot.

Comment: Acetone is nowhere near as harsh as you make it out to be. Most oil-based paints are not significantly damaged by acetone. It mostly attacks plastic compounds, like the sponge you suggested. *Lacquer Thinner* would be my suggestion, not acetone.